# Select rows of dates and missing dates in mySql

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table comprising a field called/type `datetime` of lets say of one year. The following query gives me all different numbers of months within this certain year:

```
SELECT month(datetime)
FROM foo
GROUP BY month(datetime);
```

So lets say the query returns two rows including January and November. Can/how can I manipulate this query in order to get also the missing month (February - October and December)?

Comment: If foo doesnt have data for those months, you cant select from foo only and see missing months too. You have to expand your query to allow for that

Comment: You have no aggregating functions here, so I'm not sure why you have a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: From the database you can get what is there. You can't get the missing months. Better if you create an array of all months and exclude the month that is coming from the above query. This will help you in getting missing months.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...Not sure if this is the one you are looking for.

```
    SELECT  DISTINCT MonthName FROM 
    ( 
    SELECT  MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(1, '%M')) AS MONTHNAME
    UNION 
    SELECT  MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(2, '%M'))
    UNION 
    SELECT  MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(3, '%M'))
    UNION 
    SELECT  MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(4, '%M'))
    UNION 
    SELECT  MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(5, '%M'))
    UNION 
    SELECT  MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(6, '%M'))
    UNION 
    SELECT  MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(7, '%M'))
    UNION 
    SELECT  MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(8, '%M'))
    UNION 
    SELECT  MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(9, '%M'))
    UNION 
    SELECT  MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(10, '%M'))
    UNION 
    SELECT  MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(11, '%M'))
    UNION 
    SELECT  MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(12, '%M'))
    )  AS allMonths
    LEFT JOIN 
    foo ON  MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(month(datetime), '%m')) = allMonths.MonthName
    WHERE foo.datetime is null
```

Comment: Good lord. I think he's better off solving this in his code as it's not something a database should worry about.